# New Azure Server - CSV Reader takes much longer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

We have a asp.net website that allows users to import data from a CSV file. Recently we moved to a from a dedicated server to an Azure Virtual Machine and it is taking much longer. The hardware specs of the two systems are similar.

It used to take less than a minute for data to import now it can take 10 - 15 minutes. The original file upload speed is fine it is looping through the data and organizing it in the SQL database that takes the time.

Why is the Azure VM with similar specs taking so much longer and what can I do to fix it?

Our database is using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 installed on the same VM as the website.

Comment: Are you using Windows Azure SQL Database, or running your own SQL Server on the VM?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to provide details on location of everything: That is, is everything running in the same Azure data center?

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to make a comparison between the two environments. Was the previous environment virtualized? It might do with speed of the hard disks, the placement of the Sql Server files, or some other infrastructural setup (or simply the iron). I would recommend have a look into the performance of the machine under load (resource monitor). This kind of operation is usually both processor and i/o intense. This operation should be done in parallell as well.

Hth
//Peter